# Make a list with the quarter and year based on a date range of quarters KDB+/Q

Tags: kdb

I have a list of date ranges for the past 8 quarters given by the below function

```
q) findLastYQuarters:{reverse("d"$(-3*til y)+m),'-1+"d"$(-3*-1+til y)+m:3 bar"m"$x}[currentDate;8]
q) findLastYQuarters
2020.01.01 2020.03.31
2020.04.01 2020.06.30
2020.07.01 2020.09.30
2020.10.01 2020.12.31
2021.01.01 2021.03.31
2021.04.01 2021.06.30
2021.07.01 2021.09.30
2021.10.01 2021.12.31
```

I need to produce a separate list that labels each item in this list by a specific format; the second list would need to be

```
1Q20,2Q20,3Q20,4Q20,1Q21,2Q21,3Q21,4Q21
```

This code needs to be able to run on it's own, so how can I take the first list as an input and produce the second list? I thought about casting the latter date in the range as a month and dividing it by 3 to get the quarter and extracting the year, but I couldn't figure out how to actually implement that. Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your example references globals that aren't shown in the snippet. In future, it would help people to help you if you ensured your examples can be run by others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are many ways to solve this, a function like `f` defined below would do the trick:

```
q)f:{`$string[1+mod[`month$d;12]%3],'"Q",/:string[`year$d:x[;0]][;2 3]}
q)lyq
2020.01.01 2020.03.31
2020.04.01 2020.06.30
2020.07.01 2020.09.30
2020.10.01 2020.12.31
2021.01.01 2021.03.31
2021.04.01 2021.06.30
2021.07.01 2021.09.30
2021.10.01 2021.12.31
q)f lyq
`1Q20`2Q20`3Q20`4Q20`1Q21`2Q21`3Q21`4Q21
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
crop:findLastYQuarters;
crop[0]:crop[0][1];
crop[1]:crop[1][1];
crop[2]:crop[2][1];
crop[3]:crop[3][1];
crop[4]:crop[4][1];
crop[5]:crop[5][1];
crop[6]:crop[6][1];
crop[7]:crop[7][1];

labels:()
labelingFunc:{[r] temp:("." vs string["m"$r]); labels,((string(("J"$temp[1])%3)),"Q",(temp[0][2,3])};
leblingFunc each crop;
labels
```

Comment: I expect performance isn't critical to you, but this one-at-a-time, string-based approach won't scale well.

Comment: I might also suggest that writing functions that modify global variables is not a good practice.

Comment: You can get around all of the `crop` manipulations by simply indexing `findLastYQuarters` along the first column (i.e., `findLastYQuarters[;0]`